# Are there rules of thumb for knowing when RandomVariate is more efficient than RandomReal?

Tags: performance-tuning, random

Please consider the following:

From a fresh Mathematica kernel, `RandomVariate` is more efficient for `NormalDistribution` but `RandomReal` is for uniformly distributed noise.

```
RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100]; // Timing
```

> `{0.00535, Null}`

```
RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100]; // Timing
```

> `{0.000069, Null}`

```
RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100]; // Timing
```

> `{0.00004, Null}`

```
RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[], 100]; // Timing
```

> `{0.005236, Null}`

But if I re-evaluate, I get `Timing` results that are much more similar:

```
RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100]; // Timing
```

> `{0.000051, Null}`

```
RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100]; // Timing
```

> `{0.000052, Null}`

```
RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100]; // Timing
```

> `{0.00003, Null}`

```
RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[], 100]; // Timing
```

> `{0.000058, Null}`

Does caching the distribution definition really matter that much?

Obviously `RandomVariate` has the advantage that it can generate data from mixed (not only fully continuous or fully discrete) distributions. So it is more general. But if one is generating random numbers from standard distributions like the normal or the Poisson, **is there any advantage – performance or otherwise – to using `RandomVariate` instead of `RandomReal` or `RandomInteger`?**

Comment: I didn't even know that `RandomReal` worked for distributions

Comment: @Rojo It doesn't seem to be in the main documentation for `RandomReal` in v8, but can be verified to work with `Histogram@RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1000]`. It is the way to do it in version 7, and I hadn't adapted to `RandomVariate` yet.

Comment: Interesting question

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In general you should use `RandomVariate` for distributions and `RandomReal` for uniforms. Often `RandomVariate` calls `RandomReal` or `RandomInteger` under the hood but it varies on a distribution by distribution basis. After loading any necessary symbols, on evaluation, any timing differences should be negligible.

`RandomVariate` is intended to give the flexibility to not have to think of whether the distribution is continuous or discrete (or mixed), it has also been optimized for each distribution in the system. One should always be able to use `RandomInteger` or `RandomReal` if the type is known ahead of time (and is not mixed or fuzzy in some way e.g. `EmpiricalDistribution`) but again, most of the overhead is in initializing the generator so if you are generating a large number of random numbers you shouldn't notice a big difference in timings after evaluating both `RandomVariate` and `RandomReal`/`RandomInteger`.