# Does LinearModelFit perform an ordinary linear regression (least squares)?

Tags: fitting

Does `LinearModelFit` give an ordinary linear regression? I see lots of options, but nothing like "least squares" or OLR.

Comment: Yes.  `LinearModelFit` is basically just syntactic sugar for building up design matrices that go into `LeastSquares`. It additionally gives an object (rather than just a fit) so properties can be obtained.

Comment: From *ref/LinearModelFit/Properties & Relations*: "`Fit` and `LinearModelFit` fit equivalent models". Form *ref/Fit*: "`Fit[data, funs, vars]` finds a least-squares fit to a list of data as a linear combination of the functions funs of variables vars."

Comment: In addition, the docs for `LinearModelFit[]` do [implicitly state the least-squares assumption](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LinearModelFit.html#799350985). Then again, most people don't bother to remember the usual assumptions for applying least-squares, and just happily chuck their data and model into the function without thinking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I pointed out in the comments.  `LinearModelFit` was designed to make it easy to specify models fit using `LeastSquares` given some input data by providing a language for constructing design matrices via basis functions.

`LinearModelFit` also aims to make the workflows of plotting models, computing residuals, parameter confidence intervals, etc much easier.

Here is an example which shows the equivalence of `LeastSquares` and `LinearModelFit`.  Notice that the constant basis is included by default. We have to manually add it for `LeastSquares`.

```
n = 10;
SeedRandom[1];
xdata = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 3}];
ydata = Total[xdata, {2}] + RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], n] + 2;
data = Transpose[Transpose[xdata]~Join~{ydata}];

LinearModelFit[data, {x1, x2, x3}, {x1, x2, x3}]["BestFitParameters"]

(*{1.85077, 1.48564, 1.08907, 2.36973}*)

LeastSquares[Transpose[{ConstantArray[1, n]}~Join~Transpose[xdata]], ydata]

(*{1.85077, 1.48564, 1.08907, 2.36973}*)
```

Comment: If one is taking the `LeastSquares[]` route, `DesignMatrix[]` is a very handy little thing.

Comment: @J.M. Totally agree.

Comment: Is there a reason why you use `RandomReal[NormalDistribution[]` instead of `RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], `? Can `RandomReal` work with any distribution? If yes, what's the point of `RandomVariate` anyway?

Comment: @nikie, before [`RandomVariate[]` came along](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v8/ref/RandomVariate.html), one did have to [use `RandomReal[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v7/ref/RandomReal.html) for the purpose of generating nonuniform variates. I suppose WRI has yet to remove the functionality once supported by `RandomReal[]`, so it still works to this day.

Comment: @Andy I was poking about inside `NonlinearModelFit` the other day and found that it too is syntactic sugar around `FindFit`, and moreover that the `NormFunction` option of `FindFit` could *in principle* be used with `NonlinearModelFit`, but in practice it is hard-coded to be overridden by the 2-norm. Is this an oversight or is it necessary because the properties calculations assume the 2-norm?

Comment: @OleksandrR. this is correct. I'm not entirely sure why the 2-norm. It was obviously intentional rather than an oversight. I can't tell for sure if this is due to some trouble with getting weights to work with a general norm function or of it is due to property assumptions as you say.

Comment: @nikie [Check this out](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2580/109)

Comment: @Rojo: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted to know.