# the number of values problem

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I have the following problem.

I have to generate 100 random values and make a list.

From this list I will randomly select 60 values and calculate `MeanCI` <- This procedure must be repeated 100 times.

I have to calculate the ratio between intervals `MeanCI` in which there is zero and which do not.

My code:

```
vstupnidata = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100];

Needs["HypothesisTesting`"]
For[i = 1, i <= 100, i++,
 {vyb60 = MeanCI[RandomChoice[vstupnidata, 60]],
  Print[If[vyb60[[1]] < 0 \[And] vyb60[[2]] > 0, 1, 0
    ]]}
 ]
```

Now, my program writes `1` when there is `0` and `0` when it is not. I am not able to determine their number.

Could you help me please?
Jan

Comment: Note that you have to use [`RandomVariate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomVariate.html) instead of [`RandomReal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomReal.html?q=RandomReal) to generate samples from a normal distribution. 'RandomReal' will assume a uniform distribution.

Comment: @gwr That's not true. `RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], 100]` works just fine. Look at a histogram.

Comment: @Pillsy That may well be the case but *Mathematica* is certainly not following its own documentation in that case. Using `RandomVariate` her to me seems like the "proper" thing to do. I somehow am a bit "old fashioned" in sticking to what is documented... ;-)

Comment: Interesting post with regard to `RandomReal` vs. `RandomVariate` [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2574/are-there-rules-of-thumb-for-knowing-when-randomvariate-is-more-efficient-than-r).

Comment: @Jan, delete your answer. =)) you may now upvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is your code rewritten to create the list of zeros and ones in a list, and then to count the number of ones:

```
vstupnidata = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100];
Needs["HypothesisTesting`"];
zeroOne = Table[vyb60 = MeanCI[RandomChoice[vstupnidata, 60]]; 
  If[vyb60[[1]] < 0 \[And] vyb60[[2]] > 0, 1, 0], {i, 1, 100}]
Total[zeroOne]

86
```

Comment: Why introduce `i`? Also see my comment on using `RandomReal` in this case...

Comment: @gwr - I was just trying to leave the code as similar to the OPs as possible.  There are lots of ways one might optimize...

Answer (score 5):

Lets create a "popuplation" of random numbers that are following a normal distribution and make the *confidence level* transparent:

```
Needs["HypothesisTesting`"];
pop = RandomVariate[ NormalDistribution[], 100];
SetOptions[ MeanCI, ConfidenceLevel -> 0.95 ]; (* or whatever is needed *)
```

Now we draw samples which means we are sampling without replacement and sampling with replacement (you might look up `RandomChoice` for sampling with replacement):

```
samples = Table[ RandomSample[ pop, 60 ], {100} ];
choices = Table[ RandomChoice[ pop, 60 ], {100} ];
```

Then we build confidence intervalcs for the mean of the population:

```
ciListSamples = Map[ MeanCI, samples ];
ciListChoices = Map[ MeanCI, choices ];
```

Finally we count the intervals that contain $0$:

```
Count[ #, {a_, b_} /; a < 0 && b > 0 ]& /@ {ciListSamples, ciListChoices}
```

> {94,89}

So we see, that in our test we implicitly assumed *sampling without replacement*, since the empirical result is closer to our *confidence level*. Being a Bayesian by conviction I cannot help but to remind about the meaning of a frequentist [*confidence interval*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credible_interval#Confidence_interval) which needs repeated sampling to be meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as follows:

```
ata = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100];
rc = RandomChoice[data, {100, 60}];
Needs["HypothesisTesting`"];
Count[Times @@@ (Sign /@ (MeanCI /@ rc)), -1]
```

Doing it 10 times: yielded (using `Table`):
{69, 77, 96, 69, 69, 88, 93, 92, 94, 93}